# How to get `git log` to display only commit messages?

Tags: git, git-log, git-format

Is there a way for `git log` to output *only* the commit messages, nothing else?

I'd like to do this as a starting point for composing release notes.

Comment: You might want a tool designed to compose release notes, like https://github.com/nedbat/scriv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --format=%s
```

`git log` has an option called `format` which you can use to specify the format for how each entry is logged. The option can take various "placeholders" to extract specific bits of information. `%s` is the placeholder for the commit subject. See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for more information.